# How do I move three of my grid cells to the top of the grid?

Tags: html, css

I am learning to work with "grid" and have hit a roadblock. I want to move the last three cells to the top of the grid so that I can put headers before the content but don't know how to do that. Any help is appreciated.
[image]

HTML:

```
  <div class="gridWrapper">
    <div class="gridBox heading1">Heading</div>
    <div class="gridBox heading2">Heading</div>
    <div class="gridBox heading3">Heading</div>
    <div class="gridBox a">A</div>
    <div class="gridBox b">B</div>
    <div class="gridBox c">C</div>
    <div class="gridBox d">D</div>
    <div class="gridBox e">E</div>
    <div class="gridBox f">F</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.gridWrapper {
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 500px 500px 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gridBox {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.a {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}
.b {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}
.c {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}
.d {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 2;
}
.e {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}
.f {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}
```

Comment: .gridHeadings does not match any of your HTML. You probably want something alike  `[class*='heading']` to select your headings . The first row is already filled with D A F , and the next is filled too. You have to reset grid-area for each of them to reorder the layout.

Comment: The .gridHeadings was from a previous test, sorry about that, I removed it. Also could you expand on what D A F means? And also what you mean by how they are filled? Edit: I assume you mean the cells D, A, F? What would be the grid-area I need to accomplish having the 3 heading cells first?

Comment: D A F is from `<div class="gridBox a">A</div>
    <div class="gridBox b">B</div>
    <div class="gridBox c">C</div>
    <div class="gridBox d">D</div>
    <div class="gridBox e">E</div>
    <div class="gridBox f">F</div>` standing on the first line via the rules grid-area you set for them.

Comment: Ahh brain fart, sorry about that. What would be the ideal grid-area's for each of them so the three heading cells would be on top?

Comment: Instead grid area, you could use order to make easier to read and to set . possible example for your a..f classes : `.d {order: 1;}.a {order: 2;}.f {order: 3;}.e {order: 4;}.b,.c {order: 5;}`